# How to find all the words that contain a given character the most times

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, char

Input: char (need to find the most number of occurrences of this char in words which is in array)

Output: print word which has the highest number of occurrences of given char or words if there are the same number of occurrences.

Need to find word or words which have the most number of occurrences of given char.

I wrote a program that finds and prints the word with the highest number of occurrences.
But I can't understand how to find word with given char.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char array[]="this is text. Useuuu it for test. Text for test.";
    char* buf = strtok(array," .,!?;:");
    char *word;
    int max = 0;
    char c;
    while(buf) {
        int n = strlen(buf);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int counter=0;
            for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++) {
                if(buf[i]==buf[j] && i != j)
                    counter++;
                if(counter>max) {
                    max=counter;
                    word=buf;
                }
            }
        }
        buf=strtok(0," .,!?;:");
    }
    cout << "Result: " << word << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this program result is word "Useuuu"

I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: @panilya - How about proceeding with _Input: char_?

Comment: @Armali corrected

Comment: I meant proceeding with adding the _input_ of a _char_ to your program.

Comment: this looks like one too many loops to me, and am not sure how the inner most `for` loop helps you. First, you need a char to compare against (presumably supposed to be `c`, but you're not capturing user input). Once you do that, you have the current word in `buf`, loop through that char by char, comparing with `c`. Increment a counter on a match, compare to previous greatest. If that count matches the previous greatest, `.push_back(buf)` to a vector. If there's a new greatest count, clear your buffer and `.push_back(buf)`.

Comment: @yano I need C-style array

Comment: @yano Thank you, it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem that attempts to change your code the least possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char array[]="this is text. Useuuu it for test. Text for test.";
    char* buf = strtok(array," .,!?;:");
    std::list<const char*> words{};
    
    int max = 0;
    int wrd_counter = 0;
    char c;
    std::cout << "Input char: ";
    std::cin >> c;
    while(buf) {
        int n = strlen(buf);
        int counter=0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++) {
            if(buf[j]==c)
                counter++;
        }
        if(counter>max) {
            max=counter;
            words.clear();
            words.push_back(buf);
        }
        else if(counter == max){
            words.push_back(buf);
        }
        buf=strtok(0," .,!?;:");
    }
    cout << "Results: ";
    for(const char* ccp: words){
        std::cout << ccp << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation: In the code, instead of having a single `char* word`, I use a doubly-linked list to store multiple words. I iterate through each word and find the number of occurrences of the char. I then compare to see if the word belongs in the list.

Notes: this code is rough and could be optimized. Also, if the order of the words doesn't matter, you could use `forward_list`.